# NReco video to sequence of bitmaps

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, nreco

How can I convert video to a sequence of bitmaps? I need every frame one by one and process them in memory (no disc output).

I chose `NReco.VideoConverter` but not sure which method can do this. I understand that `FFMpegConverter.GetVideoThumbnail()` is useless, since you can extract image only based on time input.

Can I use `FFMpegConverter.ConvertMedia()` ? Please, how? I've been searching for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoConverter is a .NET wrapper for ffmpeg tool, so you need to google about ffmpeg itself. You have 2 alternatives:

- use ffmpeg's "fps" filter and extract N thumbnails as image files: [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)
- use VideoConverter's ConvertLiveMedia and decode video into bitmaps ("raw_video" format); in this case you can load images into .NET Bitmap objects without using files at all.